# Natural gas mini-tank water heaters?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water, natural-gas

I have a need for a point-of-use style mini-tank (4-10 gallons) which runs on natural gas. I see a lot of electric mini-tanks of this kind but none that run on NG or even LP. Do they exist? I cannot find anything, anywhere.

I don't have the breaker box capacity for one of these electric mini-tanks nor the room for a full size 40-50 gallon tank so it has to be NG and small. Tankless is also not an option.

Comment: Can you stick a bigger (albeit not quite the size of a full tank heater) natural gas fired thing somewhere else and run some pipes to where you need this mini-tank to live?  I ask because I've seen indirect coils in the size range you're after IIRC...

Comment: Or better yet, do you already have a hydronic or steam heat supply at hand?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, right now it's running from very far away, I'm trying to reduce the delay.

Answer (score 1):

There's several models of point-of-use tankless (search `under sink` as well). I found [this unit on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TXOJQ4). There's several others as well.

The problem with a tank that small is that keeping it at temperature eats a lot more energy. A larger tank can retain its heat better. This is why a tankless is preferred for point-of-use. You only heat what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped since small electric mini-tanks exist that NG would too. The problem I've had with the tankless is the delay (up to 1 minute) on some models and I'm trying to get instant delivery for very small (<0.5 gallon) loads. Unfortunately I can't find any that advertise their time-to-delivery specs, I would need one that really is "instant".

Comment: Actually, I would also like to put a mini-tank on the outlet of an existing tankless to handle the delay problem, which is an application the electric mini-tanks are marketed for (but again, I would need natural gas)

Comment: Closest thing I can find to that is this [6 gallon LP tank](http://www.campingworld.com/shopping/item/atwood-water-heater-6-gal-lp/3687)